# No sound output when using applications installed from the Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, audio

When I'm using apps installed from the Microsoft Store (or UWP apps), I cannot hear any sound output from the application.

I've tried the following basic troubleshooting steps:

- Restart audio driver
- Ensure correct output is selected and unmuted in Windows
- Reinstall the application
- Reboot my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I am using an external DAC and "Dolby Digital" was selected as an available format. After unchecking this format, I could hear sound as expected.

To change the supported formats on a playback device:

1. Open the Sound settings via control panel

   - To quickly open the Sound applet press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter "mmsys.cpl" in the run dialog box
2. Locate the playback device and select "Properties"
3. Go to the "Supported Formats" tab and uncheck "Dolby Digital"
4. Restart the application, no need to reboot the computer